# How to reference Python elixir object items

Tags: python, python-elixir

I am trying to swap in the key name from a `request.param` for an Elixir object attribute.  Below, the Elixir object `bk` is a `Book()` which has an attribute `PrintTitle`.  `PrintTitle` also comes in from a form as a `request.param`. Rather than manually map all the parameters to the Book attributes, I would like to map them based on a simple `if in`.  However, it doesn't work, because I have the wrong syntax or method at `bk.k`.

```
if len(request.params) != 0:
        bk = Book()
        for k, v in request.params.items():
            print k, v # gives me love
            bk.k = v # no love here
        print 'Print Title:', bk.PrintTitle # value is None (obviously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just set the attribute of a Python object with a variable in this way.  One way to do this is to use the `setattr` method to accomplish this, for example here is a crude example:

```
from elixir import *

metadata.bind = 'sqlite://'
metadata.bind.echo = False

class Book(Entity):
    PrintTitle = Field(String(50))

setup_all()
create_all()

params = {'PrintTitle':'Ethyl the Aardvark goes Quantity Surveying'}

bk = Book()

print "Title in database (before): {}".format(bk.PrintTitle)

for k, v in params.items():
    setattr(bk, k, v)

print "Title in database (after): {}".format(bk.PrintTitle)
```

The result of this script is:

```
Title in database (before): None
Title in database (after): Ethyl the Aardvark goes Quantity Surveying
```

Here I'm faking out your elixir model, and I'm just using a `params` dictionary to fake out whatever you're getting in `request.params`.

So in this example `setattr(bk, k, v)` is pretty much what you're trying to do with `bk.k=v`.

**EDIT:** I should add that you need to be careful using setattr, in that you need to be sure the key from your params exists in your db model first, as elixer/sqlalchemy may not like trying to set the value of a non-existent database field.

Comment: Raceyman, that is a confirmed winner.  Thank you.  A couple of further comments... I haven't come across that `format` method before(), not sure what its supposed to do, but it didn't work for me.  I got the correct print by using `print "title in db before:", (bk.Printtitle)`.  Also, I think I can safeguard from non-existent db fields by putting the `setattr` in a `try` block?  Thanks again mate, you've really helped me out.

Comment: Aaah, I see the problem.  `setattr` will actually create an attribute that doesn't already exist in the object, right?  So I can accidentally create at attr that doesn't exist in the db.. that's what you were saying.  Hmmm....

Comment: Ok, so my understanding now is that I can use my form as the authority for field names, but the danger is that if I get a field name wrong, I won't be 'told' about it.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, objects are mutable so `setattr` will add these as properties if they don't already exist.  The difficulty here is, the object we're talking about is an elixir/sqlalchemy object so it may behave oddly if you do that.

Comment: In Python 2.7 the `.format` is used in the same way as % is used for replacing parameters in strings.  Earlier versions of Python may not allow this.

Comment: I should add that you can use sqlalchemy's `.columns` (or `.c`) property on your table object to examine your table to validate fields exist before trying to use `setattr`.